Replace SQLite Database with External SQLite Database
I am trying to replace SQLite Database with a external SQLite Database which is selected using a FileChooser.
The aim is make the database shareable across different devices. That is when changes are made in database in a device A, this database can be used in another device B.
How can SQLite database created in AppHomePath/database folder be replaced with database selected via FileChooser
EDIT
In a simulator, the following snippet saves selected database in AppHomePath instead of AppHomePath/database
String selectedDbPath = "file:///tmp/temp11455781152272037918.db";
Util.copy(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(selectedDbPath),
Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream("DbName.db"));

selectedDbPath is the path returned by FileChooser
How can DbName.db be saved in AppHomePath/database directory?

This is discussed in the Codename One Developer Guide here:

Some SQLite apps ship with a "ready made" database. We allow you to replace the DB file by using the code:
String path = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath(“databaseName”);
You can then use the FileSystemStorage class to write the content of your DB file into the path. Notice that it must be a valid SQLite file!


To the question, I have added a code that I tried to use to write selected database. But  database is saved in AppHomePath instead of AppHomePath/database directory

You're relying on a temporary file path as a hardcoded string. This value is OS specific and random per device. Mobile OS paths aren't predictable like desktop paths, you can't rely on them to remain consistent.

The temporary path is changing. The only problem is that in simulator, the database is saved in home/.cn1 directory but I need it to be saved in home/.cn1/database directory where SQLite database is usually created

You can't move the live database. You can back it up to a different location so it's available to other apps. You can copy from that location onto the current DB location. But you can't open a DB from an arbitrary file path.

There's plenty here and in the developer guide. What you should understand is the complexity of the filesystem. In Android locations changed between versions and things that are allowed in one version are no longer legal in another. It's a problematic API.

The DB will not be used by other apps, instead it will be used by the same app in a different phone. When app is launched, it creates DB, then user has options to save some records to the DB. This DB can be shared via available share apps like WhatsApp, Email etc. After receiving the DB file in device B, user in device B will launch the app which will also create a new DB. User B will then use FileChooser to select the shared DB which should replace the new DB which was created. After this is successful, user B can then view/edit records in DB.

In a simulator, app storage directory  is home/.cn1 but DB directory is home/.cn1/database. After selecting the shared DB using FileChooser, My code above saves DB in home/.cn1 but I need it to save the DB in home/.cn1/database directory which is the default database directory. How can I save the DB in  home/.cn1/database?

You can just use the share API in Display to share the db file. You don't need the file chooser. You can copy the DB file to any arbitrary location before sharing it. When receiving the file on the other device you can copy that file on top of your existing DB.

Please share an example of how to copy the DB on top of existing DB

https://github.com/codenameone/SQLSample/blob/master/src/com/codename1/apps/db/DBDemo.java#L46

Since I am selecting shared DB using FileChooser, In copyDb function I had to change InputStream i to FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(selectedDbPath)
